# How to get this WebView_Flutter to display HTML?

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I was following this tutorial to code https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPf-7rrng-8
But i'm getting a screen error on emulator screen.

[image]

I want to display the html (youtube) using the WebView_Flutter package.

Here's to code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebView extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebView({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebView> createState() => _WebViewState();
}

class _WebViewState extends State<WebView> {

  final controller = WebViewController()
  
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.disabled) 
  ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://www.youtube.com/'));

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller),
    );
  }
}
```

I've updated the package to the latest version in pubspec.yaml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. The original code was already working, in real android phone, but i was trying it out on Chrome DevTool, and it won't work there for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

You can use loadHtmlString to load html to the webview.

```
  controller.loadHtmlString(yourHtml);
```

Comment: Tried using the following, but didn't work:

```
..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.disabled);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: WebViewWidget(controller: controller.loadHtmlString('www.youtube.com')),
    )
    
    ;
  }
}
```

Comment: you shouldn't do it while assigning the controller.

From your codebase, below the line:
  final controller = WebViewController()
  controller.loadHtmlString("");// html shouldn't be a url, it should be a raw html code with the tag <html></html>

Comment: I found the reason. The original code was already working, in real android phone, but i was trying it out on Chrome DevTool, and it won't work there for some reason. Any idea on how to make it viewable in Chrome DevTool?

Comment: Okay FYI, the flutter_web doesn't work for browser.

Comment: I found out they do offer for browser, with some limitation, but enough to make it viewable for development phase - https://github.com/flutter/packages/tree/main/packages/webview_flutter/webview_flutter_web